# Adding a record to database fails

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I have a program, which uses a GET call to get some data, I then need to insert the result inside the DB. I'm getting an error when I call the program:

> DbUpdateConcurrencyException: Database operation expected to affect 1 row(s) but actually affected 0 row(s). Data may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=527962 for information on understanding and handling optimistic concurrency exceptions.

My table DDL :

```
CREATE TABLE [CampaignCustomerMatch](
  id int NULL,
  VisitorExternalId [nvarchar] (40)  NULL ,
  Url [nvarchar](250)  NULL,
  ReffererUrl [nvarchar](250)  NULL,
  ActivityDate  [nvarchar](25)  NULL
)
```

A part of my code which fails in the last line:

```
 var container = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MarkedCampaigns>(json);
 foreach (var item in container.items)
 {
      repository.addMatch(item);
 }
 await repository.saveChanges();
```

`addMatch` code:

```
public void addMatch(CampaignCustomerMatch ccm)
{
    _context.CampaignCustomerMatch.Add(ccm);
}
```

`saveChanges` :

```
public async Task saveChanges()
{
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

And my `CampaignCustomerMatch` class:

```
 public class CampaignCustomerMatch
 {
     [Key]
     public int id { get; set; }
     public string VisitorExternalId;
     public string Url;
     public string ReffererUrl;
     public string ActivityDate;
 }
```

I don't understand the error. While debugging, the container seems fine, the data is looking good as well. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: EF expects `id` column to be `identity NOT NULL`. If the table is correct, then mark the `id` property of `CampaignCustomerMatch` with `[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, `EF Core` is used `migrations` to create table which is called `Code-First`. It seems you created `Table` and `Model` separately.

If you want to manually set `id` for `CampaignCustomerMatch`, follow steps below:

1. Change `CampaignCustomerMatch` with `{ get; set; }` for properties, otherwise, all of them will be null when inserting new records.

   ```
   public class CampaignCustomerMatch
   {
       [Key]
       //[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
       public int id { get; set; }
       public string VisitorExternalId { get; set; }
       public string Url { get; set; }
       public string ReffererUrl { get; set; }
       public string ActivityDate { get; set; }
   }
   ```
2. Explicit set id like below:

   ```
       _ctx.CampaignCustomerMatch.Add(new CampaignCustomerMatch { id = 1000, Url = "www.google.com" });            
       await _ctx.SaveChangesAsync();
   ```

If you want `id` auto-generated, follow steps below:

1. Change `Table`

   ```
    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[CampaignCustomerMatch] (
   [id]                INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
   [VisitorExternalId] NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
   [Url]               NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
   [ReffererUrl]       NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
   [ActivityDate]      NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
   CONSTRAINT [PK_CampaignCustomerMatch] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([id] ASC)
   );
   ```
2. Change `Model`

   ```
     public class CampaignCustomerMatch
     {
        [Key]
       [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
       public int id { get; set; }
       public string VisitorExternalId { get; set; }
       public string Url { get; set; }
       public string ReffererUrl { get; set; }
       public string ActivityDate { get; set; }
   }
   ```

3.Insert Record without `id`

```
_ctx.CampaignCustomerMatch.Add(new CampaignCustomerMatch { Url = "www.google.com" });
await _ctx.SaveChangesAsync();
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an entire post about it in [GitHub](https://github.com/PomeloFoundation/Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql/issues/398):

> remove `.ValueGeneratedNever();` from the model for ID
>   (it is actually AutoIncrement INT primary key).